# Tab bar disappears when trying to go back from new view

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

I am very new to Xcode and have encountered an issue with my app. I am trying to create a tab bar app. On one of the tabs I have a button that brings the user to a different ViewController. I want to have it so the user can select a button that would return them to the tab that had the button. I tried to set up an action from the button to the previous view (the tabbed screen), however the tab bar disappears. I hope this is makes sense.

Here is a link to a screenshot...
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to do this is to place a UINavigationController as the root view controller of the TabBarController.  You can do this in storyboard by simply ctrl+dragging from the tabbar controller to the navigation controller and adding it as a relationship.

Here's an example using storyboards:
[image]

The next step is to set the third controller (in this case the table view controller) to your player view controller class.

Then, you can use the default back button and animation that comes with the navigation controller.  If you prefer to hide the navigation bar at the top of the screen, then you can use your custom back button to call

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

You can also choose custom animations / segues, etc. but using a navigation controller to help you navigate screens is probably the simplest approach.